# I am looking for $\circledcirc$ where the area between the two circles is shaded

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a symbol similar to $\circledcirc$ but where the area between the two circles is shaded.

In mathematical terms, this figure is called annulus.

Comment: This isn't in Unicode; at least, I can't find it.  If you have a published example of it. please provide reference, and I'll submit it for consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\annulus{\raisebox{0.5ex}{%
  \makebox[0.5em]{\rlap{\circle*{5}}\textcolor{white}{\circle*{3}}}}}
\begin{document}

foo \annulus bar

\end{document}
```

[image]